# KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 2 levels of headers and I have code like the one below.

I am getting this error: KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'

Any idea how I can solve this?

```
for row in range(len(data)):
    if (data.loc[row, ('City', 'A')] == 'Active') & (data.loc[row, ('Cost', 'A')==0]):
            data.loc[row, ('Cost', 'A')] = data.loc[row, ('Cost','B')]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

if (data.loc[row, ('City', 'A')] == 'Active') & (data.loc[row, ('Cost', 'A')]==0)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.